# Initialization of local variables

Tags: java

What's the difference between the declaring an uninitialized final variable and setting a final variable to null?

```
void A(String pizza) {
    String retVal = null;

    if (StringUtils.isBlank(pizza)) {
       retVal = "blank"
    } else {
       retVal = computeString(pizza);
    }
}

void A(String pizza) {
    final String retVal;

    if(StringUtils.isBlank(pizza)) {
       retVal = "blank"
    } else {
       retVal = computeString(pizza);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to have a `final` on the first A?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I didn't understand, but in your second example, you won't be able to reassign `retVal` after your `if-else` block. [A `final` variable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4)

> may only be assigned to once. Declaring a variable final can serve as
>   useful documentation that its value will not change and can help avoid
>   programming errors.

If you had set your `final` variable to `null`, you would not be able to reassign it in the `if` block.

Answer (score 1):

If you set a final variable to null you'll never be able to assign anything else to it...
A final variable (itself) can never change.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that a final variable can never be changed to have another value.

Answer (score 0):

In this one, the `retVal = null` accomplishes nothing. You give it a value of null. You never have code that uses that value. Then you give it another value, depending on whether you do the if-then or the else part.

In code that falls where I've added the comment, you can use or change the value of `retVal`.

```
  void A(String pizza) {
      String retVal = null;
      ... code in here could use it or give it a new value ...
      if(StringUtils.isBlank(pizza) {
         retVal = "blank"
      } else {
         retVal = computeString(pizza);
      }
      ... additional code here might change it (and can use it's value) ...
   }
```

In this one, you are required to give `retVal` a value everytime the method is called. Your if-then-else code does that. The value can never be changed after it is given a value.

One difference is that the compiler would tell you if you used `retVal` before giving it a value. It would, reasonably, tell you that the variable has no value yet.

```
   void A(String pizza) {
      final String retVal;
      ... code in here cannot use it or give it a value, too ...
      if(StringUtils.isBlank(pizza) {
         retVal = "blank"
      } else {
         retVal = computeString(pizza);
      }
      ... additional code here cannot change it but can use it's value ...
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

`final` means:

- You **have to assign something** (even if it's null)
- You **can't change the reference** to anything else afterwards (but you can, of course, modify
  the referenced object).

The meaning is highly *semantic*, and makes sure you won't accidentally forget to care about what to assign, and you can code with the guarantee that the value is not accidentally changed. 
Omitting this modifier just removes that guarantee, nothing else.